# Working with template suggestions on Drupal 8

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I need Drupal to use a **custom page template** if the URL contains a particular **_GET** parameter.

In **D7** I would do something like this in the theme's template.php:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      if($_GET['isCustomTpl'] == true)
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =  'page__myCustomTpl';
}
```

It doesn't work in D8 though (I would have been surprised by the opposite, considering all the architectural changes in the theme layer).

Any ideas?

Bonus question: is it possible to define such a function in a module, so that i can release it publicly without having the users to edit their themes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can implement the new [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8) hook.

> Alters named suggestions for a specific theme hook.
>
> This hook allows any module or theme to provide altenative theme function or template name suggestions and reorder or remove suggestions provided by hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK() or by earlier invocations of this hook.

You can use it like so

```
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (\Drupal::request()->query->get('foo') == 'bar') {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__myCustomTpl';
  }
}
```

You can implement it in either a module or theme

Comment: Great, working perfectly! Hopefully it'll evolve into a fully-functional pjax module for d8!

Comment: if I want to do it by theme, I must put this code in template.php file like drupal 7? and the theme file name must be page_myCustomTpl.html.twig? am I right?