# Why does Drupal (8) not discover my custom taxonomy term template?

Tags: theming, 8

Following the instructions on [how to create a custom template for taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/152639/12010) I managed to add a template suggestion for a particular view mode of the taxonomy term entity by using [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x):

```
function linkup_theme_suggestions_taxonomy_term_alter(&$suggestions, $vars, $hook) {
  if($vars['elements']['#view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy-term--teaser';
  }
}
```

(*linkup* is the name of my custom theme)

This seems to work as I can see the template suggestions when I print the twig debug information:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'taxonomy_term' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * taxonomy-term--teaser.html.twig
   * taxonomy-term--15.html.twig
   * taxonomy-term--group.html.twig
   x taxonomy-term.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/content/taxonomy-term.html.twig' -->
```

But for some reason Drupal does not pick up the template which is located in themes/linkup/templates/taxonomy-term--teaser.html.twig

I think the naming is correct (unlike Drupal 7 in 8 you dont need to fiddle with underscores to match dashes in file names)

If I add a template called taxonomy-term.html.twig to the theme then that is discovered.

Am I missing some of Drupal 8's logic to discover the custom template?

Comment: How does your hook_theme() look like?

Comment: have you rebuilt the caches ?

Comment: I do not have a hook_theme() ... & sure I rebuilt the caches ;)

Answer (score 7):

You need to use underscores in your suggestion (but continue to use dashes in your template file name):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() for taxonomies.
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
function HOOK_theme_suggestions_taxonomy_term_alter(&$suggestions, $vars, $hook) {
  if($vars['elements']['#view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__teaser'; // note underscores
  }
}
```

you could also leave out your condition and do:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() for taxonomies.
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
function HOOK_theme_suggestions_taxonomy_term_alter(&$suggestions, $vars, $hook) {      
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $vars['elements']['#view_mode'];
}
```