# How can create custom twig template for particular page

Tags: theming, 8

I want to create custom template for particular pages. Single template for multiple page in drupal 8.

Answer (score 1):

> #### Twig Debugging
>
> It’s great that we have the ability to override our template files,
> but we are still left with the question of how we are to know which
> template file needs to be overridden in any particular case. After
> all, template files are nested one inside the other—which one contains
> the markup that we want to change?
>
> This brings us to the killer feature of Drupal 8 theming—Twig
> debugging. Getting started is very easy. Inside of the sites/default
> folder is a file named service.yml. Inside that file you will find a
> setting for Twig debug. This setting will be set to false by default.
> Simply change it to true as shown in the image below:
>
> [image]
>
> As usual, clear your cache after making this change. When we return to
> our page and inspect the markup we will find debugging information
> added in the form of code comments. Here’s an example of what our home
> page markup will look like when inspected in DevTools:
>
> [image]
>
> You can see the debug info provides the path to the new template file
> we have created. This information is repeated for other template files
> found on the page, providing a fast and easy way of finding the file
> you need to override or edit.
>
> Important: Do not edit template files in core! Copy the file to your
> theme and edit that version instead.
>
> Also included are file name suggestions for overriding the currently
> active templates. If you’ve ever had to track down the correct
> template file to override in Drupal 7, then you know what a huge
> improvement this is.
>
> Author: [John Hannah](https://www.lullabot.com/who-we-are/john-hannah)
>
> Source and more great twig info: [Drupal 8 Theming Fundamentals, Part 2](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-8-theming-fundamentals-part-2#h2)

**Note:** In the 2nd pic, the `x` shows you the current twig template that is being used. In this example it's page--front.html.twig

To answer your Q, enable twig debug and go to your page and with your browser inspect element. The debug will suggest you all the template names you can use for that page.

**PS:** Don't forget to turn off twig debug before your site goes live.

Comment: I want use one template for multiple page.

Comment: or create your own suggestion in template_preprocess_page(&$variables), see here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98002/working-with-template-suggestions-on-drupal-8

Comment: @SourabhSurana then look at the suggestion that appears in all pages (test 2 or 3 pages) in twig debug and use that twig name. I haven't done this myself yet, but I assume when you look at a page that is not the front page, there should be some suggestion that uses the content type name. You should go with that one, as you probably don't want to affect the front page.

Comment: It is not working after enable debug it show node with not id in console all page have different id can you tell me how can i write condition using node id or slug for call one template on more than one page.

Comment: I want use one template for multiple page like as wordpress

Comment: @SourabhSurana https://www.drupal.org/node/2354645 here they list all the types you should find. Under Nodes, there is `node--type.html.twig` so if you want to use this and your content type is articles, then it's `node--articles.html.twig` (this will affect all article pages/nodes).

Comment: If you want to affect all pages regardless of their content type, then use `node.html.twig`, but keep in mind this will affect everything, including the front page. You may want a different template for you home page, you can always then create `page--front.html.twig` so it uses that template for the front page.

Comment: But it work for all type i want use for couple of them not for all.I need it for page not node.

Comment: @SourabhSurana then use `node--nodeid.html.twig` ex: if node id is 10 then it's `node--10.html.twig`

Comment: if i want user same template for multiple id i need to copy same template multiple time or we can use same template multiple time if yes can you tell me

Comment: @SourabhSurana the reason the front page use `page` is because the front page is not a node. `page--node--nodeid.tpl.php` it will affect the edit page (ex: node/1/edit) which I don't think you want. `same template for multiple id i need to copy same template multiple time` yes you just copy and change the id on the template name. Ex: `node--1.html.twig` copy, paste, rename `node--2.html.twig`

Comment: please tell me if i use another way  create post type for all page that need same template and use type template(node--type.html.twig) this is also right approach or not

Comment: @SourabhSurana yes, that is the right approach.

Comment: @No Sssweat Thanks for your knowledge sharing i am new in drupal i have 2 year experience of working with wordpress can you tell me how can i learn drupal fast

Comment: @SourabhSurana youtube and google-ing is your best friend :)

Comment: @SourabhSurana 1) [Watch and Learn](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUBR53Dw-Ef818EUxzNoWKcQ7PYUXpFFA) 2) [OS Training](https://www.youtube.com/user/ostrainingcom/playlists) 3) [Drupal Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGrplWMKeOL0QygtYOsRViQ/playlists)